# Is there something like a TreeLayout in Swt?

Tags: user-interface, layout, treeview, eclipse-rcp

Im building a Eclipse RCP Application, where a user can create boolean rules. My idea for the GUI can you see in the picture:[image: picture]. Basically a rule is displayed like a tree, where the user can click on nodes to add another node in the tree.
My question is: Is there something like a Tree Layout in RCP/SWT to automatically arrange view elements like a tree? Or could i create something like this with the existing layouts?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a standard Tree layout or something like this in SWT. You can always simulate it, by, for example using a [Canvas](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-graphics/SWT_graphics.html) and drawing shapes as you like. It is pretty powerful solution. Check out [Gantt chart](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/ganttchart/ganttchart.php) for example.

Other possibility would be to use Eclipse [GEF](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/), which seems to be exactly what you need.

Comment: Sadly im building an E4 Application and GEF 3.9 doesnt seem to work with E4. But i will check out your other suggestions